# Static map with encoded polygon not displaying

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I'm having a difficult time figuring out why this static map isn't displaying.. I'm using encoded lines and polygons.  The lines display ok but not the polygon.  I put the encoded polygon string into google's [Interactive decoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) and it works fine.

Encoded Polygon

```
wl}vFlm{zN?gNfKIM}L|h@OSlB`Bj@l@h@nEGD{D|CNXrO`CHDdFaCHMxCkKNGgNyX{@?zOk^
```

This url is:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3|color:0x000000|enc:a||vFze|zN|E}cA&path=weight:3|color:0x000000|enc:qj{vFny{zNyTaO}QtWoE|W&path=weight:3|fillcolor:0x0000FF|color:0x0000FF|enc:wl}vFlm{zN?gNfKIM}L|h@OSlB`Bj@l@h@nEGD{D|CNXrO`CHDdFaCHMxCkKNGgNyX{@?zOk^&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false
```

I also tried url encoding the polygon string with no luck.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3|color:0x000000|enc:a%7C%7CvFze%7CzN%7CE%7DcA&path=weight:3|color:0x000000|enc:qj%7BvFny%7BzNyTaO%7DQtWoE%7CW&path=weight:3|fillcolor:0x0000FF|color:0x0000FF|enc:wl%7DvFlm%7BzN%3FgNfKIM%7DL%7Ch%40OSlB%60Bj%40l%40h%40nEGD%7BD%7CCNXrO%60CHDdFaCHMxCkKNGgNyX%7B%40%3FzOk%5E&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false
```

They were encoded using:

```
points_array = mapOverlays[i].getPath(); 
enc = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(points_array);
```

Was hoping someone more knowledgeable than I could spot why this isn't displaying for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is something missing in the encoded path, when I decode the path and then encode the path again there is a additional @-sign at the end(it will also be added when I use the interactive encoder).

With the @ the polygon will be loaded: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3|color:0x000000|enc:a%7C%7CvFze%7CzN%7CE%7DcA&path=weight:3|color:0x000000|enc:qj%7BvFny%7BzNyTaO%7DQtWoE%7CW&path=weight:3|fillcolor:0x0000FF|color:0x0000FF|enc:wl%7DvFlm%7BzN%3FgNfKIM%7DL%7Ch%40OSlB%60Bj%40l%40h%40nEGD%7BD%7CCNXrO%60CHDdFaCHMxCkKNGgNyX%7B%40%3FzOk%5E%40&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false